# Do any language lack a present tense different from that used in Indoeuropean languages?

Tags: linguistic-typology, tense

i wonder if the present tense (a tense denoting the present and only the present) is a universal in languages that have tense. Or do some languages have a present tense that extends into the recent future and/or past?

If there are such languages, does this tense have other effects on the tense paradigm?

Comment: A assume you mean "in languages which mark tense", so you're excluding aspect-marking languages from discussion. English would be an example. "I'm going", "I'm arriving at noon" refers to the future.

Comment: And _He walks to work_ refers to the past and probable present.

Comment: I think you will have difficulty finding any language with "a tense denoting the present and only the present".

Comment: "Next week he goes to Spain". "Next week he is going to Spain". Two so-called "present tenses".